# rails import with on_duplicate_key_update not working in mysql db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I had an issue, when im using on duplicate key update in MySQL DB the SQL show on the log doesn't use on duplicate key update.

Code

```
MyModel.import a, validate: false, on_duplicate_key_update: [:name, :company_id]
```

SQL Log

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_multiple_break` (`id`,`name`,`company_id`) VALUES (100,'test 101',1)
```

[rails console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmVA7.png)

because of that my import process always throws an error record not unique.
'''

Comment: Do you have any DB indexes on `name` column?

Answer (score 0):

The key name you are using is wrong, it's `on_duplicate_key_update` and not `on_duplicate_update_key`

```
MyModel.import data, validate: false, on_duplicate_key_update: [:name, :company_id]
```

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import#duplicate-key-update

Comment: sorry for the typo, but in my actual code written on_duplicate_key_update. but still same the SQL for on duplicate didn't show